# (Ruby-On-Rails4) Route error when calling method from ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to retrieve some information calling a method through ajax. It seems I'm missing something on my code, because when troubleshooting from chrome inspect I get an "url not found" error. My Models are Warehouse & Product. What i would like to accomplish is when a product is selected from the select_tag field, populate a text_field with a default price for that product. This is what I have so far:
1. select_tag view:

```
<%= select_tag "product_selection", options_from_collection_for_select(Product.all, "id", "name") %>
```

2. warehouses.js

```
    $(document).on("change", '#product_selection', function() {
    $.ajax({
       url: "/warehouses/get_price",
      type: "GET",
  dataType: "json",
      data: { product_id: $('#product_selection option:selected').value() }, // This goes to Controller in params hash, i.e. params[:file_name]
  complete: function() {},

   success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
              // Do something with the response here
              document.getElementById("default_price").value = data.default_price;                                                            
            },
     error: function() {
              alert("Ajax error!")
            }
  });
});
```

3. warehouses_controller.rb

```
def get_price
  @price = Product.find(params[:product_id]).price
    if request.xhr?          
      render :json => { :default_price => @price }
    end
end
```

4. routes.rb

```
  resources :products
  resources :warehouses

  resources :warehouses do
    member do
      get 'get_price'
    end
```

The message I get from Chrome Inspect:

> jquery.self-c64a743….js?body=1:10244 GET http://localhost:3000/warehouses/get_price?product_id=2 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Ajax call to the method (url: "warehoueses/get_price") was failing because I generated the get_price method inside the private methods section on warehouses_controller.rb so that was basically my mistake. Thanks anyway for the help!

Comment: Glad you got it figured out. It seemed that the routing was not the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Rails routing here: [Rails Routes](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Routes are read from the top down, and so it looks for :get_price in the first reference to warehouses. One choice is Combine the routes:

```
 resources :products
 resources :warehouses do 
      member do
           get 'get price'
      end
 end
```

That will actually point to

```
 /warehouses/{:id}/get_price
```

To lose the restful id, you could try

```
 resources :products
 resources :warehouses do 
      collection do
           get 'get price'
      end
 end
```

That should respond to

```
/warehouses/get_price
```

and then pass the appropriate parameter.

Alternatively, To get the route that you are looking for, you could

```
 get 'warehouses/get_price', to: 'warehouses#get_price'
 resources :products
 resources :warehouses
```

Notice the custom route is above the resources.

Comment: Wow, thanks for your so fast response. I Implemented as suggested but still getting the same error

Comment: You can just list it per my edit ... perhaps try that? Just make sure that it is above the :warehouses resource.

Comment: I tried all the alternatives but still having the same issue. One question, if I type the specified route on the url bar, i.e { http://localhost:3000/warehouses/get_price } should I have some type of response regardless I don't have a view (get_price.html.erb) created for that controller method? Thanks in advance for your help